# Change class in angularjs through controller

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me to change the class of input[type=button] dynamically using angularjs and controller.

```js
app.controller('anodekeypadcntrl',function($scope){
 
 
 $scope.clickTwentyFour = function(event){
   In this function I need to highlight the button (adding the .active class to it) 
 };
                             
});
```

```html
<div class="keypadcontainer" ng-controller="anodekeypadcntrl as child">
  ------
  <input type="button" value="24" id="twentyFour" class="twentyfour anodeKeypadButton"
 ng-click="clickTwentyFour($event)" />
  -------------
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for this. In your markup just do something like:

```
<input type="button" value="24" id="twentyFour" class="twentyfour anodeKeypadButton"
ng-click="clickTwentyFour($event)" ng-class="myDynamicClass" />
```

This way you can set `myDynamicClass` to be either a single string containing a CSS class or an array of strings directly from your controller

```
// controller code
$scope.myDynamicClass = 'some-css-class';
```

This will get appended to the HTML. If you look at the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) docs you will see that you can even attach functions which return a class, or write the classes directly in the HTML with conditions attached.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add class then 
Try this :

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#twentyFour' ) );
myEl.addClass('active');
```

you can replace the the things in the querySelector with your required id.

Comment: Although this is a perfectly fine method, we wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel here. Angular already provides built-in functionality for setting dynamic classes and styling so we shouldn't complicate our code with selectors and such.

Comment: Thats true but there is no clear explanation or case how the button should have an active class so question will have this simple answer.if it was more specific dynamic binding of the class would be a better option

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-class` to dynamically add class to your `div`or button or whatever

Here is a working plunker with your code

http://embed.plnkr.co/rzS8GV975BHRk83xhsPx/preview

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using 'ngClass'. Also note that you can use a expression to decide the class of any html element.

Suppose there is a model element named $isButtonActive=false;

```
    <input type="button" value="24" id="twentyFour" class="twentyfour anodeKeypadButton" ng-click="clickTwentyFour($event)"
 data-ng-class="isButtonActive? 'Active': 'Passive' "/>
```

By changing the value of the 'isButtonActive' from controller, 
(isButtonActive value to 'true', the 'Active' class is added)
you can control the css class.